# Scanning menu items that disappear from screen with Tosca

Tags: ui-automation, tosca

I am trying to scan a context menu which appears on screen only on mouse over or clicks using Tosca. This is a windows based application, so inspecting the control will not work. How can Tosca scan / record such context menus?

Tried recording with Tosca, but clicks are not happening on the context menu while recorder is ON

Answer (score 1):

Try using scan the application using classic Engine or you have to enable some engines which are present in Tosca. It will work with Tbox scan also.